# How to launch a application or show a Window from Titanium Android Service?

Tags: android, titanium, android-service

I have a service in Titanium App which will be running every 50 seconds.

Can I show a window in my App at a particular time from service ?

Showing means, I want to make the desired window on top even if my App is not running (only service will be running).

Comment: Like an annoying pop-up ad similar to web browsers?  I hope not!  I believe the acceptable way is using push notifications.

Comment: No, similar to how WhatsApp is showing the PopUp notification and from there we can reply to chat, or how Facebook's chat heads works ?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this may help you creating the notification, call the method in you wanted. 
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Android_Notifications

Comment: Good Sreekumar. To make a popup, create a custom alert box.

Comment: Vishnupriyan -- Ti.UI is not accessible from android service and am too unable to create window as like native AlarmManager showing alarm notification. Have you tested before you answer??